# Error: error getting chaincode deployed: filed to calculate dependencies: incomplete package: google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/prototext

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, iota

i have been trying to use iota connector with hyperledger fabric but when i try to build chaincode i get this error.

`Error: error getting chaincode deployment spec for enter code herefabric-demo-app: error getting chaincode package bytes: failed to calculate dependencies: incomplete package: google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/prototext`

any idea why this happens?

I have tried to install the module using go install, but it appears that if it is installed.

If so, I would greatly appreciate a helping hand :)

Comment: try `go mod init` command inside your `chaincode` directory. then try `go vendor` to create a `vendor` directory. It  will install all the dependencies that you are using.

Comment: ok i will try that thank you very much for the help :)